# invalid upstream 'origin/master' on bare repository with git-dir

Tags: git

For a few years now I've been using [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles) approach for handling my dotfiles. In summary, this is what I do when I set up a new computer:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone --bare https://github.com/xxx/xx.git $HOME/.config/xx
alias config='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.config/xx/ --work-tree=$HOME'
config checkout -f
config config --local status.showUntrackedFiles no
config remote set-url origin git@github.com:xxx/xx.git
```

I also have a corresponding alias definition in my `.bashrc`

This is great (if you haven't tried it, you should)! However, I run into problems whenever I need to perform pretty much any git operation other than add/commit/push/pull.

For example:

```
$ config merge origin/master
merge: origin/master - not something we can merge

$ config rebase origin/master
fatal: invalid upstream 'origin/master'
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Check your remote branches : `config branch -r`, you can also check the branches listed directly on the remote : `config ls-remote origin`. If no `master` branch exists there : you have your answer. Otherwise : run `config fetch`.

Comment: Do you have branch named `origin/master` or you want to merge and rebase from `master` that is in origin?

Comment: Try `git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

Comment: @ElpieKay Amazing, that worked! Thank you! If you write that as an answer I'll mark it as the solution. If you could also give a little detail on what it does/why it works that'd be brilliant as well.